# Video Touch Slider with HTML, CSS & JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, video

I recently was playing around with the code showcase in this tutorial: [Touch Slider CodePen](https://codepen.io/bradtraversy/pen/ExNVwgZ)
I would like to use something like this but with videos instead of images.

I swapped the HTML, JS, and CSS code to work with the  tag. With this, the code does work and you are able to scroll over one video initially just like the images had worked. After this, it seems the js 'isDragging' or some event in te JS seems to freeze and I am unable to slide to another video or image.

Would anyone be able to play around with the JS shown in this CodePen and get a working slider with videos?

Thanks!

````
  slides = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.slide'))

let isDragging = false,
  startPos = 0,
  currentTranslate = 0,
  prevTranslate = 0,
  animationID = 0,
  currentIndex = 0

slides.forEach((slide, index) => {
  const slideImage = slide.querySelector('video')
  slideImage.addEventListener('dragstart', (e) => e.preventDefault())

  // Touch events
  slide.addEventListener('touchstart', touchStart(index))
  slide.addEventListener('touchend', touchEnd)
  slide.addEventListener('touchmove', touchMove)

  // Mouse events
  slide.addEventListener('mousedown', touchStart(index))
  slide.addEventListener('mouseup', touchEnd)
  slide.addEventListener('mouseleave', touchEnd)
  slide.addEventListener('mousemove', touchMove)
})

// Disable context menu
window.oncontextmenu = function (event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  event.stopPropagation()
  return false
}

function touchStart(index) {
  return function (event) {
    currentIndex = index
    startPos = getPositionX(event)
    isDragging = true

    // https://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe/
    animationID = requestAnimationFrame(animation)
    slider.classList.add('grabbing')
  }
}

function touchEnd() {
  isDragging = false
  cancelAnimationFrame(animationID)

  const movedBy = currentTranslate - prevTranslate

  if (movedBy < -100 && currentIndex < slides.length - 1) currentIndex += 1

  if (movedBy > 100 && currentIndex > 0) currentIndex -= 1

  setPositionByIndex()

  slider.classList.remove('grabbing')
}

function touchMove(event) {
  if (isDragging) {
    const currentPosition = getPositionX(event)
    currentTranslate = prevTranslate + currentPosition - startPos
  }
}

function getPositionX(event) {
  return event.type.includes('mouse') ? event.pageX : event.touches[0].clientX
}

function animation() {
  setSliderPosition()
  if (isDragging) requestAnimationFrame(animation)
}

function setSliderPosition() {
  slider.style.transform = `translateX(${currentTranslate}px)`
}

function setPositionByIndex() {
  currentTranslate = currentIndex * -window.innerWidth
  prevTranslate = currentTranslate
  setSliderPosition()
}  ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `<img/>` tag with `<video/>` and replace the img reference in JS

HTML:

```
<div class="slider-container">
      <div class="slide">
        <h2>Airpods</h2>
        <h4>$199</h4>
        <video width="320" height="240" controls>
          <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/367564948.sd.mp4?s=d969af3ae466e775628a8d281105fd03a8df12ae&profile_id=165&oauth2_token_id=57447761"/>
        <video />
        <a href="#" class="btn">Buy Now</a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <h2>iPhone 12</h2>
        <h4>$799</h4>
        <video width="320" height="240" controls>
          <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/334344435.sd.mp4?s=d367341a941ffa97781ade70e4f4a28f4a1a5fc8&profile_id=165&oauth2_token_id=57447761"/>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Buy Now</a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <h2>iPad</h2>
        <h4>$599</h4>
        <video width="320" height="240" controls>
          <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/369639344.sd.mp4?s=b892fce959245aa4ae7ab08bc4b1af2766acdf4e&profile_id=165&oauth2_token_id=57447761"/>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Buy Now</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.7;
}

.slider-container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: inline-flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
  cursor: grab;
}

.slide {
  max-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  user-select: none;
}

.slide img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 60%;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.slide h2 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.slide h4 {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
}

.grabbing {
  cursor: grabbing;
}

.grabbing .slide img {
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
```

JS:

```
/*
  This JS code is from the following project:
  https://github.com/bushblade/Full-Screen-Touch-Slider
*/

const slider = document.querySelector('.slider-container'),
  slides = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.slide'))

let isDragging = false,
  startPos = 0,
  currentTranslate = 0,
  prevTranslate = 0,
  animationID = 0,
  currentIndex = 0

slides.forEach((slide, index) => {
  const slideImage = slide.querySelector('video')
  slideImage.addEventListener('dragstart', (e) => e.preventDefault())

  // Touch events
  slide.addEventListener('touchstart', touchStart(index))
  slide.addEventListener('touchend', touchEnd)
  slide.addEventListener('touchmove', touchMove)

  // Mouse events
  slide.addEventListener('mousedown', touchStart(index))
  slide.addEventListener('mouseup', touchEnd)
  slide.addEventListener('mouseleave', touchEnd)
  slide.addEventListener('mousemove', touchMove)
})

// Disable context menu
window.oncontextmenu = function (event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  event.stopPropagation()
  return false
}

function touchStart(index) {
  return function (event) {
    currentIndex = index
    startPos = getPositionX(event)
    isDragging = true

    // https://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe/
    animationID = requestAnimationFrame(animation)
    slider.classList.add('grabbing')
  }
}

function touchEnd() {
  isDragging = false
  cancelAnimationFrame(animationID)

  const movedBy = currentTranslate - prevTranslate

  if (movedBy < -100 && currentIndex < slides.length - 1) currentIndex += 1

  if (movedBy > 100 && currentIndex > 0) currentIndex -= 1

  setPositionByIndex()

  slider.classList.remove('grabbing')
}

function touchMove(event) {
  if (isDragging) {
    const currentPosition = getPositionX(event)
    currentTranslate = prevTranslate + currentPosition - startPos
  }
}

function getPositionX(event) {
  return event.type.includes('mouse') ? event.pageX : event.touches[0].clientX
}

function animation() {
  setSliderPosition()
  if (isDragging) requestAnimationFrame(animation)
}

function setSliderPosition() {
  slider.style.transform = `translateX(${currentTranslate}px)`
}

function setPositionByIndex() {
  currentTranslate = currentIndex * -window.innerWidth
  prevTranslate = currentTranslate
  setSliderPosition()
}
```